# Prolog - Creating a list by iterating facts

Tags: list, prolog

I am new in Prolog and wanted to learn it. I have been trying to create a list while iterating facts but list that was created one step back refreshing and lost the data. How can I keep the data and add elements to list?

```
funct(a,b,1).
funct(b,c,2).
funct(b,d,3).

creatingList(X,Y,R):- funct(X,Y,A), funct(Y,Z,B), \+member(B,R) , append(R,B,R).
```

I tried that , but when I trace it keeps losing data, which I expect is R = [1,2,3].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@User is correct:

```
?- findall(funct(X,Y,Z), funct(X,Y,Z), Functs).
Functs = [funct(a, b, 1), funct(b, c, 2), funct(b, d, 3)].
```

`setof/3` and `bagof/3` might also apply, but their semantics are a little more complex.